# Lost ability to add GPG key and stable repo from deb file

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

**Background -**

I installed the protonVPN latest release. It provides a deb file which launches "Ubuntu Software" when double clicked. This allows you to install it which adds the ProtonVPN GPG key and stable repo URLs.

The program would not run after install so I uninstalled and tried the beta release version. Then I continued to have the same issues.

At this point I notice errors around the sources PUBKEY not matching which ended up with me deleting the sources.list URLs and GPG key.

**Problem -**

When I try to install GPG key and stable repo from deb file, it installs but nothing is added to sources.list. I can not find the URLs that should be there or understand why the deb file installs without adding them.

Running `apt-get update` after installing the deb file does not add the package info so I can not install the program anymore.

**Question -**

How can I get the source URLs and GPG keys installed by the deb file setup manually or what would cause this issue where deb file no longer adds the correct URLs and keys?

**What I Tried -**

I have restarted computer, shut down terminal and reopened, manually checked
***/etc/apt/sources.list.d***
&
***/etc/apt/sources.list***

Comment: I would be asking the VPN company this as it is their software.

Comment: My question is not to fix the VPN, it is to understand how to work through the problem on Ubuntu regarding GPG keys and finding URL for source.